# jQuery AJAX works with IE but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would appreciate if someone could tell me what I need to do to get this code to work in both IE and Firefox.  In Firefox the confirm prompts work, but the AJAX request does not occur.  Firebug reports this error: jquery-1.11.1.js (line 9631).  This is the jquery code found at that line:

```
xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#frmDelFiles").submit(function(event) {
        var names      = "";
        var id_array   = [];
        var elements = document.getElementsByName('files2del');

       for (var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++)
       {
          if (elements[i].checked)
          {
            //alert("ip_attachments record " + elements[i].id + " - " + elements[i].value + " is checked.");
            var response = confirm("Do you consent to delete the " + elements[i].value + " file?\n\nClick OK if Yes, otherwise Cancel.");
            if (response == true) {
                id_array[id_array.length] = elements[i].id;
                if (names == "") {
                    names = elements[i].value;
                } else {
                       names += ", " + elements[i].value;
                    }
            }
        }
        }

        if (names == "") {
            alert("Zero files have been selected for deletion.");
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "del_ipa_rcd.php",
                data: {id_array: id_array, names: names},
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(response){
                   $("#delete_result").html(response);
                   //alert(response);
                }
            });
       }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<form name='frmDelFiles' id='frmDelFiles' method='POST' class='frmFileUpload'>
<input type='submit' value='Delete Checked Files' name='delFiles' class='btnSubmit' />
</form>

...
...

while ($attach_row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   echo "            <input type='checkbox' name='files2del' id='" . $attach_row['id'] . "' value='" . $attach_row['name'] . "'>\n";
   echo "            <a target='_blank' href='/php/dwnld_blob.php?column=content&tbl=ip_attachments&id=" . $attach_row['id'] . "'>" . $attach_row['name'] . "</a><br>\n";
}
```

Comment: You have a massive XSS vulnerability there in your `<input type='checkbox' name='files2del' id='" . $attach_row['id'] . "' value='" . $attach_row['name'] . "'>\n";` You probably want to use a template system and not concatenate strings. I also suspect your use of `mysql_fetch_array` is vulnerable to SQL Injection. You might want to double check. Your XHR response is also a XSS vulnerability. You just straight up take HTML and render it from your response...

Comment: So..... What was the error?

Comment: @Kevin, the error is the AJAX del_ipa_rcd.php does not get called in Firefox.  Firebug reports an error in jquery.js on line 9631.  Can I get a more descriptive error somewhere else?

Comment: Yes. firebug reports an error on line 9631. What error is it reporting? A line number isn't an error message.

Comment: Additionally, you should be using the error callback of $.ajax to get more information.

Comment: @Kevin, the Console Panel of firebug shows the POST URL in red.  The Error Panel is blank.  If I right click on the red URL: and select "Open in New Tab" which opens the AJAX PHP in a new tab then the AJAX PHP runs fine without an error.  Can you tell me where I can find additional error information?

Comment: inspect the request under the network tab. If it's red, with no error, it's likely not returning 200 status code.

Comment: @Kevin, thanks.  I looked there and there are no red requests.  However, the AJAX call does not have a status code (it is blank) and it shows 0 B for size.  There is a "Param" tab in the details, but not a "Response" tab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62185/discussion-between-brian-g-and-kevin-b).

Comment: @Derek,  Your comment is useless and provides absolutely no benefit or help!!!  I did something wrong? Duh, why do you think I asked the question.  How it gets a 2 is beyond me.

Comment: @BrianG - Well it is a comment, not an answer. If you expect a detailed answer you should probably look at the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this AJAX request problem by changing a few lines in the html and one line in the jQuery.

Here are html changes:

```
<form name='frmDelFiles' id='frmDelFiles' method='POST' class='frmFileUpload'>
    <input type='submit' value='Delete Checked Files' name='delFiles' class='btnSubmit' />
</form>
```

changed to:

```
<button class="btnSubmit">Delete Checked Documents</button>
```

Here is the one jQuery change

```
$("#frmDelFiles").submit(function(event) {
```

changed to:

```
$("button").click(function() {
```

Now the AJAX request works fine in both IE and Firefox.